# Cannot display a collection of beans in JSTL

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, el, javabeans

I have this Bean

```
public class Bank {
    private String id;
    private String bankname;

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setBankname(String name){
        this.bankname = name;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getBankname(){
        return bankname;
    }
```

And also A Servlet that receiving an ArrayList taken from MySQL.
This arraylist is using that Bean I mentioned earlier.

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
int manyRow = 15;
ArrayList<Bank> bankList = new MysqlUtil().getBankTableData(15);

HttpSession sess = request.getSession(true);
try {
    sess.setAttribute("susunan", bankList);
    sess.setAttribute("panjang", bankList.size());
    request.getRequestDispatcher("table/bankTable.jsp").forward(request, response);
    return;
} finally {
     out.close();
}
```

And this is my JSP accessing them by iterating it:

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${susunan}" var="bankData">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${susunan.id}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${susunan.bankname}"></c:out></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

But the result I got is

> ERROR for input string : "id" and for input string : "bankname"

Why does the JSP seem to not recognize my bean?

Comment: if you want to attack the problem first initalize the strings with some value and check if those values are able to populate on JSP .Then check your query of it populating correctly the values to bean

Comment: If you want to add more information, simply edit your question. If you'd like to discuss a specific answer, just use the comment facility under the answer. The answer field is reserved for answers that directly solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <c:forEach items="${susunan}" var="bankData">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${bankData.id}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${bankData.bankname}"></c:out></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The variable named susanan is the entire list; it does not have an id. The variable named bankData is the individual beans.

Comment: so then... how could we iterate that Susunan variable because we dont have getter in the jstL (in the jsp interface).....?

Comment: The way it is stated in the example code is all you need. The variable is in scope there. If you are still getting empty values then there is another problem. Are you sure that the getBankTableData() method is actually returning anything?